# How to disable ripple in Material Design React

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am talking about this repository.
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui

I want to know how to disable the ripple effect from all components.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

For anyone that cares about how to do so on an **individual button** by button bases, be sure to apply the `disableRipple` property to the individual button you care to disable the ripple effect for.

for example

```
import {Button, IconButton} from '@material-ui/core';
function RiplelessButtonSampleComponent(props)
{
   return (
            <div>
               <strong>Icon Button</strong>
               <IconButton disableRipple onClick={this.showModal} variant="text" color="primary">
                  <i className="fal fa-chevron-right" />
               </IconButton>

               <strong>Standard Button</strong>

               <Button disableRipple onClick={this.showModal} variant="text" color="primary">
                  Click Me for No effect
               </Button>
            </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 24):

Here's the [MUI v5 way](https://mui.com/getting-started/faq/#heading-how-can-i-disable-the-ripple-effect-globally)

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableRipple: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Also use `<ThemeProvider theme={theme} /> ... </ThemeProvider>` in V5 when wrapping the components.

Answer (score 22):

According to [**Material-UI documentation**](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/), you can disable the **ripple effect** globally by providing the following in your theme:

```
import React from "react";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    props: {
      // Name of the component
      MuiButtonBase: {
        // The properties to apply
        disableRipple: true // No more ripple, on the whole application!
      }
    }
  });
  return (
    // You need to wrap your component with <MuiThemeProvider> tag
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
          Primary
        </Button>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

You can check this **[working sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/disabling-ripple-effect-in-material-ui-i4rk0)**.

Answer (score 9):

While searching the solution for same question in case of react material UI, if someone stumbles upon this page like me, Quick way to remove ripple from a React MaterialUI Button component is to add "disableRipple" attribute.

```
<Button disableRipple>Button Caption</Button>
```

P.S. I am using @material-ui/core version 4.5.1

Comment: And, if you're using a `ButtonGroup` you want to just put it on the `ButtonGroup` tag and child buttons inherit.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the default property by adding this to componentDidMount() at the highest level React component that is inside of the `MUIThemeProvider`:

```
componentDidMount(){
  //Do this to all components you would like to disable the ripple effect.
  EnhancedButton.defaultProps.disableTouchRipple = true;
  EnhancedButton.defaultProps.disableFocusRipple = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to [Andrey's answer](/a/69329893/22166610) that you may want to add it to the ButtonGroup theme options as well, otherwise it will override, and Buttons will have the ripple effect inside `ButtonGroup`'s even though the `Button` `disableRipple` defaults to true.

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiButtonBase: {
            defaultProps: {
                disableRipple: true,
            },
        },
        MuiButtonGroup: {
            defaultProps: {
                disableRipple: true,
            },
        },
    },
});
```