# How to disable ripple in React's Material UI library's Tab Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Tab component of the Material UI library and want to disable the default ripple effect it has . After referring to [How to disable ripple in Material Design React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211994/how-to-disable-ripple-in-material-design-react), I tried doing this:

```
const CustomTab = withStyles({
    ...
    MuiButtonBase: {
        disableRipple: true
    }
    ...
})(Tab);
```

but it didn't work, please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can choose to disable ripple individually on the tab component by adding a prop disableRipple

```
<Tab disableRipple label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
```

If you wish to disableRipple globally you can choose to override the default theme using ThemeProvider and createMuiTheme

```
import Demo from "./demo";
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    MuiButtonBase: {
      // The properties to apply
      disableRipple: true // No more ripple, on the whole application !
    }
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Demo />
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

**[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ecxz3?file=/index.js:0-499)**

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        // The props to apply
        disableRipple: true, // No more ripple, on the whole application !
      },
    },
  },
});
```

https://next.material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-disable-the-ripple-effect-globally