# How to disable ripple effect on Material UI Input?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How to disable ripple or highlight color of the `TextField` component from Material UI in React?

[image]

I have tried overriding theme:

```
theme.props.MuiTab.disableRipple = true
```

```
theme.props.MuiButton.disableRipple = true
```

```
theme.props.MuiButtonBase.disableRipple = true
```

or adding custom CSS:

```
// disable Ripple Effect
.MuiTouchRipple-root {
display: none;
}

// disable FocusHightlight
.MuiCardActionArea-focusHighlight {
display: none;
}
```

based on the suggestions from the issue raised here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/240

Is there a way I could remove the ripple effect on the input when focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way using `withStyles`:

```js
const CustomTextField = withStyles({
  // Override default CSS for input
  root: {
    '& .MuiInput-underline': {
      // Remove the ripple effect on input
      '&:after': {
        borderBottom: 'initial',
      },
    },
  },
})(TextField);

...

// Usage
<CustomTextField />
```

Codesandbox for comparing different solutions with Button and TextField:

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: I don't use REACT, but it seems you need to disable the ripple effect upon creation of the theme [Material UI FAQ: How can I disable the ripple effect globally?](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-disable-the-ripple-effect-globally). While the example disables the effect globally, you may be able to name specific a `prop`. Another here on Stackoverflow [SO42211994](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57728913/2015909) with example.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I have tried that and it works well for buttons, tabs, etc. but not the input field

Comment: Your JS code example does not show this. Did you really try it when defining the theme? (Just making sure!). There may be a distinct difference between creation time and setting `...disableRipple = true` somewhere in the code.

Comment: @RenevanderLende no worries! I have added the code sandbox in the answer

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me

```css
underline: {
  "&:before": {
    borderBottom: `2px solid var(--border)`,
  },
  "&:after": {
    borderBottom: `2px solid var(--border)`,
    transition: 'none',
  },
  "&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error):before": {
    borderBottom: `2px solid var(--border)`,
  },
}
```