# How to disable long click effect on a material-ui button?

Tags: material-ui

I have this btn with an icon insdie of it i click for a long time it created and undesiered effect around the icon any clue how to remove this action ?

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import ViewListIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ViewList";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button style={{ MuiButtonBase: { disableRipple: true } }}>
        <ViewListIcon />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-voice-u06m3?file=/index.js:0-387)

Comment: I think you're talking about the ripple effect. To disable ripple, you need to pass `disableRipple` prop to the Button component `(Not as a style)`. [Here](https://v4.mui.com/api/button/) is the API of the available props of the `Button` component. The updated [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-lewin-dno8k?file=/index.js:217-230)

Comment: please submit an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable ripple in Material Design React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211994/how-to-disable-ripple-in-material-design-react)

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211994/how-to-disable-ripple-in-material-design-react) in the above comment has better answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `disableRipple` prop to `Button`

```js
<Button disableRipple>
  <ViewListIcon />
</Button>
```

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button-base/), the prop `disableRipple` on MUI Buttons, such as `Button` or `IconButton` disable ripple effect.

```js
<Button disableRipple>
  <ViewListIcon />
</Button>
```

By default, a ripple is activated when the host element of the `matRipple` directive receives mouse or touch events. Upon being pressed, a ripple will begin fading in from the point of contact, radiating to cover the host element. Each ripple will fade out only upon release of the mouse or touch.

Without a ripple there is no styling for `:focus-visible` by default. Be sure to highlight the element by applying separate styles with the `.Mui-focusVisible` class.

Read more about this here: [Ripple](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview).